# CSS unordered list indent space to the left and right

Tags: html, css

Basically I have navigation bar inside my "main" div, and its indented to the left.

[image]

I cannot figure out where does this indentation come from, I tried padding/margin 0, padding-left/margin-left 0 but still nothing, It won't move even one inch!

I even tried mozilla firebug inspector to try to find out if I selected it right, basically no solution.

And here is html/css file if someone would have time to take a sneaky-beaky onto HTML code:

```css
body {
  background-color: #000;
  color: white;
}

/* Style for tabs */
#main {
  color: 111;
  width: 600px;
  margin: 8px auto;
}

#main > li, #main > ul > li
{ list-style:none; float:left; }

#main ul a {
  display:block;
  padding:6px 10px;
  text-decoration:none!important;
  margin:1px 1px 1px 0;
  color:#FFF;
  background:#444;
}

#main ul a:hover {
  color:#FFF;
  background:#111;
}

#main ul a.selected {
  margin-bottom:0;
  color:#000;
  background:snow;
  border-bottom:1px solid snow;
  cursor:default;
}

#main div {
  padding:10px 10px 8px 10px;
  *padding-top:3px;
  *margin-top:-15px;
  clear:left;
  background:snow;
  height: 300px ;
}

#main div a {
  color:#000; font-weight:bold;
}
#male, #female, #all, #new {
  color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>2015 Race Finishers</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="my_style.css">
  </head>
  <body>
    <header>
      <h2>2015 Race Finishers</h2>
    </header>
    <div id="main">
      <ul class="idTabs">
        <li><a href="#male">Male Finishers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#female">Female Finishers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#all">All Finishers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#new">Add New Finishers</a></li>
      </ul>
      <div id="male">
        <h4>Male Finishers</h4>
        <ul id="finishers_m"></ul>
      </div>
      <div id="female">
        <h4>Female Finishers</h4>
        <ul id="finishers_f"></ul>
      </div>
      <div id="all">
        <h4>All Finishers</h4>
        <ul id="finishers_all"></ul>
      </div>
      <div id="new">
        <h4>Add New Finisher</h4>
        <form id="addRunner" name="addRunner" action="service.php" method="POST">
          First Name: <input type="text" name="txtFirstName" id="txtFirstName" /> <br>
          Last Name: <input type="text" name="txtLastName" id="txtLastName" /> <br>
          Gender: <select id="ddlGender" name="ddlGender">
          <option value="">--Please Select--</option>
          <option value="f">Female</option>
          <option value="m">Male</option>
          </select><br>
          Finish Time:
          <input type="text" name="txtMinutes" id="txtMinutes" size="10" maxlength="2" />(Minutes)
          <input type="text" name="txtSeconds" id="txtSeconds" size="10" maxlength="2" />(Seconds)
          <br><br>
          <button type="submit" name="btnSave" id="btnSave">Add Runner</button>
          <input type="hidden" name="action" value="addRunner" id="action">
        </form>
      </div>

    </div>
    <footer>
      <h4>Congratulations to all our finishers!</h4>
      <br>Last Updated: <div id="updatedTime"></div>
    </footer>
    <script src="scripts/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/my_scripts.js"></script>
    <script src="scripts/jquery.idTabs.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

This is just for learning purpose, but I would really love if I could somehow solve this problem, biggest thing is that I have no clue where does it come from.

Comment: do you think we would open .rar file? post the question with some relevant code with the problem you're facing.

Comment: Please post a complete code example in your question. I will not download some random .rar file.

Comment: Learn to use your browser’s developer tools – they make finding stuff like this real easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply add `padding: 0;` to `#main ul` or `.idTabs` and that fixes your problem.

Also you may want to move `list-style: none;` from `#main > li, #main > ul > li` to `#main ul` as well: it's just nicer semantics.

The padding comes from the user default stylesheet. If you inspect the `<ul`> tag you'll notice something along the lines of `-webkit-padding-start: 40px;`. So by setting `padding:0` we are ensuring all browsers have no padding, thus solving your problem. It's a good habit to add `margin:0;` and `padding:0` to ensure all browsers look the same (if not, at least have more resemblance).

Comment: This solved my problem completely, I would still love to know where that padding is coming from, but oh well. :) Thank you sir.

Comment: Very welcome :) Added a brief explanation for you just to help clarify things

Comment: Oh yes, I knew, even wrote that I think there is default indentation from ul as it sets bullets and indent by default to do the job, but for our custom navigation menu its completely not necessary. Found that bad boy now. Completely understand everything, thank you tons, now next time I will know where to look at when I get something that I can't understand from looking at code, under the hood everything is there basically! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't understand where the indentation is coming from. But I found using a negating margin solves the problem for now.

```
#mian ul{ margin-left: -2.5em;}
```

The rest of the part you can figure it out.

Let me know please if you find where the indentation is coming from and if the left margin works for you.

Comment: Works like charm, thank you :) I don't figure it where it comes from either! Probably some ul bug after bullets got removed or something... At least thats what I figure out.

Answer (score 0):

The reason of this space(padding-left) is ul. < UL > element has some left padding by default in order to follow listing structure. So here problem is nothing but the same.

It has padding-left:40px; by default, i guess.

Add this to your CSS file:

```
ul
{ padding: 0;
}
```

[WORKING:DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/fj4n9kmc/)

Comment: @Cipiripi Try adding padding-left:40px; it will make no change, then try padding-left:0px;.